# Install Ubuntu without CD or USB

Tags: system-installation

On my laptop I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 but both my USB and CD drives are broken.
I want to know how to install without needing the USB or CD. If you can help that is welcome.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Wubi is no longer supported but you can do an install over a network or internet, the directions are long so I am just going to post a link to them. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Server_and_network_installations

Answer (score 1):

You can install Ubuntu using the Netboot installation.  This will require your computer to be able to boot over the network. For more details, refer to the following link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot

Answer (score 0):

The method is not recommended. But give it a try. If you have windows installed, you can use wubi. 
On ubuntu 12.04 that was one of the installation methods. You can install it within Windows. 
If you want to boot ubuntu, you must restart it and select it from the windows bootloader menu.
If you have ubuntu booted, you can try to update from there to next LTS version. 
And i think there is no another way, without an functional CD or usb Port.